# Finding a Russian character in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsstring, string-matching

I have to check out whether a russian character is present in a `NSString` or not.

I am using the following code for that:

```
NSCharacterSet * set = 
 [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"БГДЁЖИЙЛПФХЦЧШЩЪЫЭЮЯ"] 
   invertedSet];

BOOL check =  ([nameValue rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound); 

return check;
```

But it is always returning `FALSE`.

Can anybody give me an idea what is wrong in my code?

Thanks

Comment: That double negation is a bit of an overhead...

Comment: @H2CO3 Double negation is commonplace in Russian language :)

Comment: @Rachit I see that some chars is missing from Russian alphabet: А, В, К, М, Н, О, Р, С, Т

Comment: Also lowercase letters.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, but that is not a Russian site and not a Russian language.

Comment: @holex You didn't get the joke, did you?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, it is not a site for jokes either.

Comment: @holex Right :):):):):):):)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, your condition checks that non-Russian (technically, non-Cyrillic) characters are absent from the string, not that Cyrillic characters are present in the string. Your code will return `YES` only for strings that are composed entirely of Cyrillic characters that do not have an equivalent character in the Latin alphabet<sup>1</sup>.

To fix this problem, remove the inversion, and invert the check, like this:

```
NSCharacterSet * set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"БГДЁЖИЙЛПФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"];

return [nameValue rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You have forgotten to include the soft stop `Ь` in your list, it looks like a lower-case `b`, but it is not the same character.

Comment: @Shmidt That was an incorrect edit: the OP excluded all Russian characters that resemble Latin characters on purpose, not by mistake.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I didn't see anything in text about purpose, so I think it was a mistake — some Russian characters look like Latin but it's not Latin. Subject of the post says only about Russian, so some users can be confused with this answer. Anyway I created my own for them.

Answer (score 5):

I used `dasblinkenlight`'s answer but I included full Russian alphabet including lowercase characters:

```
@interface NSString (Russian)
- (BOOL)hasRussianCharacters;
@end
@implementation NSString (Russian)
- (BOOL)hasRussianCharacters{
    NSCharacterSet * set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"];
    return [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound;
}
@end
```